# .delete() rendering wrong path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement delete method for my objects and I ran into some trouble.

For example, my function is referring to a wrong URL `/users/1/tasks?id=1` but in my case I want it to refer to `/users/1/tasks/1`. How to resolve the issue?

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', ['ngResource']);

  app.factory('Task', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/users/:user_id/tasks/', {user_id: '@user_id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}});
     }
   ]);

  app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {

      $scope.user = current_user

       $scope.deleteTask = function(task){
       alert(task.id);
       if (confirm('Are you sure')) {
         var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
         Task.delete({ user_id: $scope.user.id, id: task.id },
         function(success){
           $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);
         });
        }
       };

   }
  ]);
```

Comment: change /users/:user_id/tasks/  to  /users/:user_id/tasks/:id

Comment: @maddygoround It helped, thanks.

Comment: @maddygoround And I'm just wondering, Why do we have to specify `{id: '@id'}` after the resource route?

Comment: you don't  event have to provide  {user_id: '@user_id,id :'@id'},you already doing that in your delete call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you should do the path like `/users/:user_id/tasks/:task_id`  to get the proper URL `/users/1/tasks/1`.  Otherwise in it's current form it's going to read the part after `/tasks/` as a query parameter, which is what is happening currently.